# How can I find the row number of a certain string in a text file in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a Python script which opens a list of csv files hosting mass spectrometry data, gathers the data with Numpy.genfromtxt, makes calculations based on these data using statsmodels and returns the results in a compiled excel file.
Inside the CSV file the header and the internal structure may be of variable size depending on the running conditions of the experiment.

For now I use a config file which I read with configparser, and I use different config files for different experimental conditions. However this is pretty clunky.

What I want to do is to measure the header size and the length of the dataframe, instead of reading it from a config file. The data for each isotope starts with a string, such as:

```
*#ISOTOPE, 'Ar36:L2S1'* and *#ISOTOPE, 'Ar37:L1S1'*
```

followed by the data for each isotope (3 columns), for example:

```
*#ISOTOPE, 'Ar36:L2S1'*

No, Time, Intensity

1, 101.4685919, 1.845379369941e-003

2, 102.4901003, 2.153738546096e-003

.....

599, 701.1342959, 2.087938052439e-003

600, 702.1343039, 2.000204060898e-003

(blank line)

*#ISOTOPE, 'Ar37:L1S1'*

No, Time, Intensity

1, 101.4685919, -1.103785922163e-004

2, 102.4901003, 3.526673114000e-004
```

etc.

I want to determine the row number of the data and the length of the data for each isotope.

When I then try to import the whole datafile without ignoring the headers (to count the row index) I get errors related to the number of columns. I tried usecols = 1 to ignore the rest but this does not work.(valueerror)

I assume there is there a simple solution to this, but my programming skills are not very good so far.

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_csv(...)`?

Comment: @mrzo they're mentioning `usecols=1` which is a pandas.read_csv option so chances are pretty high that's what they're using to load the CSV files to start with.

Comment: Hello, my method above is with np.genfromtxt, not with pandas. I use numpy for part of the the actual calculations. I tried now with pandas but, it gives an error " expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3.  Im pretty new to programming unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear but my understanding is you have a bunch of CSV-ish datasets inside a single file, with a header line (starting with `*#ISOTOPE`) and a blank "footer" line for each?

Depending on the size, an option might be to open files the basic way (using the `open` builtin), then loop on:

- process the magic header (read one line and parse that)
- copy everything to a temporary file or StringIO until the first blank line
- parse the tempfile or StringIO as CSV, process as usual

Repeat until the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I have a whole bunch of csv -ish files with complicated headers that I read in batch, and each csv file has 5 subsections that I read in. My current program is told where to start looking for data and ignores the headers. I would like the program to recognise where to start, basically to "measure" the header length, which is effectively counting the rows until the occurrence of a certain string.

Comment: The principle is the same: open the files using `open`, extract whichever information you need (iterating the file or using `read` or `readline`) then pass that onto the rest of the pipeline (probably closing the file beforehand).

Comment: I see that this should work, I will give it a shot... :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, Masklinn pointed me in the right direction. The following code returns the index of the sections I am looking for:

```
FileList = (glob.glob("*.csv"))
for FileToProcess in FileList:
        with open(FileToProcess) as readfile:
            for cnt, line in enumerate(readfile):
                if "#ISOTOPE" in line:
                    print("Line {}:{}".format(cnt, line))
        readfile.close
```

Thanks a lot!